# gitlab pipeline to azure static web app doesn't seem to work

Tags: azure, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to take a very vanilla create-react app and deploy it to Azure static web apps via a Gitlab pipeline.

[image: project structure]

I've create the .yml file like so

```
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

variables:
  API_TOKEN: $DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN
  APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR'
  OUTPUT_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/'
  VERBOSE: 'true'

build:
  stage: build
  image: node:18.15.0-bullseye
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $OUTPUT_PATH

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.gitlab.com/static-web-apps/azure-static-web-apps-deploy
  script:
    - echo "App deployed successfully."
```

and there are no reported errors at all, but nothing happens to the azure site.  I continue to see nothing but the "Your Azure Static Web App is live and waiting for your content"  message when I view it.   The logs on the pipeline build seems fine... but its like it doesn't upload my artifact?   I'm not sure how to get more diagnostic information.

Build logs

```
Compiled successfully.
File sizes after gzip:
  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.5a84f9dc.js
  1.79 kB   build\static\js\787.d8457f89.chunk.js
  541 B     build\static\css\main.073c9b0a.css
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:
  npm install -g serve
  serve -s build
Find out more about deployment here:
  https://cra.link/deployment
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:03
Version:      16.3.1
Git revision: d240d5bb
Git branch:   16-3-stable
GO version:   go1.20.5
Built:        2023-09-14T23:38:58+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Uploading artifacts...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=3776 revision=d240d5bb version=16.3.1
C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\RNyC64A_\0\XXXX\secure-web-app/build/: found 20 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=20386 responseStatus=201 Created token=3stNxfN_
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:02
Job succeeded
```

Deploy logs

```
Resolving secrets
00:00
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell (powershell) executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on XXXXXXX...
Getting source from Git repository
00:32
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/Gitlab-Runner/builds/RNyC64A_/0/XXXX/secure-web-app/.git/
Checking out c333aa81 as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Removing build/
Removing node_modules/
git-lfs/3.0.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.17.2)
Skipping Git submodules setup
Downloading artifacts
00:03
Version:      16.3.1
Git revision: d240d5bb
Git branch:   16-3-stable
GO version:   go1.20.5
Built:        2023-09-14T23:38:58+0000
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
Downloading artifacts for build (20386)...
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=windows pid=26872 revision=d240d5bb version=16.3.1
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        host=git.xxxx.com id=20386 responseStatus=200 OK token=3stNxfN_
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ echo "App deployed successfully."
App deployed successfully.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with my yml file.   The issue was actually the runner itself was set up in "shell" mode and if you need to use "docker" mode.  Otherwise the image to deploy to azure static web apps won't work